# Is there a fuel calculator for RV travel in USA/Canada?

Tags: budget, canada, automobiles, motor-homes

I'm thinking of taking an RV across Canada. However, having never used one before, I'm struggling to figure out how much fuel it might use.

I'm hoping there's a calculator for a Compact or Standard RV (from Cruise Canada) in terms of fuel consumption, that I can then use to work out the potential cost, roughly.

Does anyone know of such a method, website or have experience in fuel consumption with these vehicles?

Comment: Checkout Cost2drive. I think it does Canada, but am not sure. If it doesn't work, assume 10mpg and $4.25/gallon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The website [Cost2Drive](http://beta.costtodrive.com/) is a fuel calculator that works in Canada or the U.S., and taking into account the make and model of your car and pump prices, calculates the cost of a trip.  [Here's an example drive](http://beta.costtodrive.com/from/Toronto-ON-Canada/to/Tobermory-ON-Canada/1/custom/10/12/Regular/) from Toronto to Tobermory, ON - It's surprisingly difficult to get the default routing to stay in Canada!

One of the things I love is a comparison of the cost to fly.  Keep it mind, when you discover that Toronto to Vancouver in a RV comes out to $903.

The list of RVs is fairly scarce, however, so my 1986 Toyota Coachman isn't listed. As such, I need to click on the "Can't find your car" and enter its pathetic, if typical mileage - namely 10mpg.

In general a Class C RV can expect 10 - 12 mpg.  Class A's (the big buses) are in the 8 - 10 mpg range.  Fifth Wheels are completely dependent on the truck, but if you're getting 15mpg, praise the Lord!  Ditto for Class B vans.

I typically plan my costs at 10mpg (or 3 miles per $), and then celebrate that I was a little bit harsher in my calculations than reality.

Be aware that older RV's in particular don't take kindly to the mountains, so Banff will suck down the gas more than Manitoba.

Finally, remember that gas in Canada is pretty expensive.  Back in 2010, when I drove from Northern Virginia to [Tobermory, ON](http://www.tobermory.org/page/home/Tobermory_Welcomes_You), I found gas prices creep steadily upwards as I went further north.  At the time, gas was in the low $3's when I left DC, mid $3's in PA (and the mountains were terrifying as I would floor the gas and still manage no more than 20 mph!), high $3's in NY, and about $4.25/gallon in Canada.  As a Kiwi, I know you are used to buying gas in liters (which Canada does), but for us 'Muricans, remember that you have to multiply by (roughly) 4.  You know you're going to be in trouble when buying gas by the quart.

Answer (score -1):

Fueleconomy.gouv is fantastic to calculate fuel consumption. It would beperfect if we could add towing weight

Comment: Could you indicate why it's fantastic?