# Alaska, from Anchorage to Fairbank, car/hotel vs MotorHome

Tags: hotels, car-rentals, alaska

I would love to travel to Alaska, the flight tickets are already expensive, and the hotel I think those prices are like too high for being Alaska, so came to my mind the option to rent a motorhome, is that a good Idea??, I would travel Alone, I just want to drive trough Alaska and see the landscapes around.

I also thinking that's probably that the motorhome could be too big to go everywhere as a car do.
So, should I stay with the hotel and rent a car? or should I rent the motorhome?

Comment: hi, welcome to travel.SE! While noone can tell what you should do or if it is a good idea, we can help you if you state clear criteria. Please rephrase your question as such. For example, ask about the costs and the convenience of travelling with a motorhome. You'll figure by yourself if you should choose this option.

Comment: I think this is another case of a good answer actually making a broad question good enough. Don't close.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a common misconception that using a motorhome is cheaper than flying, or even staying in a hotel.

Trust me, when you check the rates at the various motor home rental agencies, it's not.  Cruise America, for example, charges $900 for 10 days, *plus* a fee for every mile you drive.  And that is before you consider the gas, which at 10mpg, adds up.  Yes, if you already own one, you save, but renting mitigates that.

[Is there a fuel calculator for RV travel in USA/Canada?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11090/is-there-a-fuel-calculator-for-rv-travel-in-usa-canada/11094#11094) will answer the cost of gas piece. The extra gas (10mpg vs. 30mpg) often has a way of costing about as much as the hotel.

Trent over at the [TheSimpleDollar.com](http://thesimpledollar.com) once did a cost comparison - and when his site is back up, I'll link to it :)  In the end, the gas and depreciation was a wash over a hotel.

In the end, its going to cost about the same to stay in a motor home or get hotels.  The difference isn't in the cost, but rather the freedom a motor home brings. As a proud and happy RV'er, that alone is worth it.

Alaska in particular has a reputation as being friendly to RVs - the wide open spaces, lack of bridges, etc... actually make driving it fairly common.  Still, the Alaska Highway is notoriously long - "miles and miles of miles and miles."  Again, if you're looking for cheap, the time savings of a plane should be factored against the drive.  If you like the drive (and I do), do the drive - but don't think of it as a magic way to save money.

Comment: Can confirm that. We travelled to BC and considered renting a RV. Cheapest RV would have cost 2500 EUR for 2 weeks + fees for mileage + gas + camping site fees. Rental car cost us 700 EURs, ho(s)tels cost us ~1500 EUR for 2 weeks. But was high season (August).